# How to go to the end of a C block from the beginning of the block and vice versa in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a block of code in C like this-

```
enum colors { //---->I am here
RED,
BLUE,


/* Hundreds of colors in between */


}; // -----> I want to reach here in the easiest possible way.
```

Going from the end of the block back to the beginning of the block would also be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically the `%` key does it (in *Normal* mode). It works both ways. You may want to check [the relevant documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_29.html#29.3) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Shift + 5" key to jump between beginning/ end of the code block.

Comment: Is that really accurate? On alternative keyboad layouts, I really don't think the normal command is suddenly something else, you will still need to type `%`

Comment: There might be keyboard layouts where '%' isn't at shift+5 though.